Inno Setup image missing in Installed Apps
I'm using Inno Setup to generate an installer file and it's working well in that sense. I'm just after a detail of the image associated with the file not showing in the Installed Apps. Ideally would prefer to have the image showing there as it's showing correctly in the desktop icon. Anyone aware of how can this be fixed?

Thanks

Add a DisplayIcon string value to your uninstall registry information. It should contain the full path to your .exe (or a .ico if your .exe does not have an embedded icon).
For Inno Setup, UninstallDisplayIcon will do this for you.

thank you! I managed to get it showing :)

The solution:
[setup]
...
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\program.exe

program.exe is the name of the exe file in the app
